# JQuery add a span class into a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I'm using jQuery in my app. My goal here is to display the validation errors next to the text field, but actually it replaces the div content.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nom d'équipe</label>
    <div class="controls" id="nom_equipe">
        <input type="text" name="nom_equipe" value="" class="input-xlarge">                 </div>
</div>
```

So I retrieve the form errors with ajax and this is what i do :

```
if(data.validate == false)
{
    if(data.nom_equipe != '')
    {
        $("#nom_equipe").append("span").addClass("label label-important").text(data.nom_equipe);
    }
}
```

But it replaces the whole content of my div id=nom_equipe like this :

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nom d'équipe</label>
    <div class="controls label label-important" id="nom_equipe">Le champ Nom équipe est requis.</div>
</div>
```

Finally, this is what I wish to have :

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Nom d'équipe</label>
<div class="controls" id="nom_equipe">
    <input type="text" name="nom_equipe" value="" class="input-xlarge"> 
    <span>The field nom_equipe is required </span>
            </div>
```

PS : the content into span div comes from the ajax request.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`append("span")` will not append a span element, just the text `"span"`. To append a span element you need `append('<span>')`.

Also the class will be added to the main element the way your code is written and the way jQuery works

Concatenating the html string with class and text included requires less function calls and is often less code than calling individual methods to create the element

```
$("#nom_equipe").append("<span class='label label-important'>"+data.nom_equipe+'</span>');
```

The main problem with your existing code is that even with the chaining used, the element that `text()` is being used on is still the original `$("#nom_equipe")`. `text('text string')` will replace all html within that element

Comment: Thank you both for the solution. I put this answer as solved thanks to the explaination given

Comment: @charlietfl hey, my friend, how come that you start with `"` and end with `'` in your append? Is this really possible?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev certainly is possible, I likely did it due to intiial copy/paste but changed to my own preference for another part. `var str = 'a' + "b" + 'c'` is perfectly valid ...all the open and close quotes match

Comment: @charlietfl ohh  yeah.. :) right, you had a variable there. It doesn't look very clear but you're right, it's perfectly valid.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) if you want to retain the contents you already have.

```
$("#nom_equipe").append("<span class='label label-important'>" + data.nom_equipe + "</span>");
```

> [Append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts content, specified by the parameter, to the end
>   of each element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: still not appending a span with this solution and class will be added to main element